# Pycharm won't allow to run a file. Shows run unittest option only.

Tags: unit-testing, pycharm

I have a file and it has bunch of methods starting with prefix "test". Now I want to run this file and it has a `__name__ == "__main__"` construct which sets it up. However, when I right click or go to run menu bar, It (Pycharm) only shows me "Run Unittests in xxx". This is very annoying behaviour.

Can someone please tell me how to avoid this.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you right-click inside the 'if **name** == "**main**"' block, it will show you the regular "Run script" option instead of "Run unit test". After that, you can save the created run configuration and use it to run the script.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out by myself. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: @VaidAbhishek I have the same problem, but in my case the solution didn't work. I also tried to rename all the methods and classes starting with test, and restart the ide, but no success so far!

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ 4.1.3, and I'm only seeing the option to run doctests on a file, even though the file no longer has any doctests, and it makes no difference if I right click in the `if __name__ == "__main__":` block.

Comment: Ah, if you already have a run definition for the particular python file, even a previous autogenerated one, the context menu will only offer that run choice; you must delete it under Run -> Edit Configurations... first, and after that the context will propose a new one based on the file contents again.

Comment: This does not work.  Impossible to delete unittest config or it doesn't exist as a created one to delete.

Comment: Right-clicking on name==main works, but none of the options to disable this stupid automatic unit testing work. So now it is necessary to look for the name==main every time. This just started happening out of the blue, so I guess it is a bug.......a bug that has been around for more than 3 of years!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Sorry to add to an old question. The only way I got this to work was by highlighting the code in the aforementioned block. this gave me the option to do unit tests, run normally, etc. after deleting previous configurations as mentioned below by Andrew. I'm also running:

`Professional PyCharm 2017.1.2
Build #PY-171.4249.47, built on April 26, 2017` if that matters to future readers

Comment: This should not be marked as the correct answer -- if you've previously run the unit tests on that file, IntelliJ runs those instead of running as the script. 2019 -- has been an issue for 4 years.

Answer (score 17):

One detail missing from @yole’s answer is that you need to delete any existing configurations associated with the file before you can right-click and get it to run/debug. So, the full procedure is:

1. Delete any existing configurations for that file by going to ‘Run -> Edit Configurations’ in the menu.
2. Right click inside the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block
3. Choose `Run`
4. Save the configuration

After that, you should be able to run or debug the file as expected.

Comment: There's no way to save.  There's no way to delete (defaults can't be deleted).

Answer (score 10):

I couldn't get @yole's answer to work but i did  manage by going to
run > edit configurations > new configuration (the plus sign) > select python,
now input a name (mine was 'stop the bloody unittest') and select the correct script

Comment: This also doesn't work.  Run unittest still the only one available in the drop down.

Comment: @AbstractSpacecraft In the context menu drop-down (right-click within code) I have the same problem as you but in the Run drop-down in the upper right corner of PyCharm I could select the new config.

Answer (score 6):

Using PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2 EAP. Here is how I did it:

1. From the `Run` menu select `Run...`. (Or use its keyboard shortcut)
2. A popup menu appears that should contain at least three entries: `edit configuration...`, `my_script_name`, and `Unittests in my_script_name.py`. Click on the right arrow of `my_script_name`.
3. If the configuration is not saved, you should be able to see a `save configuration` option in the arrow menu. Choose it.

If the configuration changed again, follow the same steps but this time choose `run` in the last step.

Answer (score 2):

As to me, "If you right-click inside the 'if name == "main"' block" will not work.

For example if you want to run "dlib_fun_test.py", you should ‘Edit Configurations’ , remove it from "python tests", and then add it to the above "Python".

The below is my configure:

[image]

Or you can also run the script, in bash console by python just_test.py.

[image]

Comment: Maybe reference the version you are using so its good for new users?

Comment: win10 pycharm2016-anaconda3 is also useful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, deleted my `.idea` folder in the directory of the project I was working on and was able to run my tests normally again:

```
PyCharm 2018.2.4 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-182.4505.26, built on September 19, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b8 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

P.S. You can your version of PyCharm by going to Help -> About