# Pycharm 4.0.4 cannot run file, shows 'Run Doctests' in context menu instead

Tags: python, pycharm

I have copied a .py file from my teacher, and loaded it in to a project in Pycharm 4.04. When i tried to right-click and run it, it shows "Run Doctests in 'foo.py'" instead of the regular "Run 'foo.py'", and i cannot find out how to run it normally.

I searched for 'doctest' in settings and found nothing, and in PyCharm documentation [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/run-debug-configuration-doctest.html#d152822e122), there's nothing about disabling doctests either.

I found a similar question here:
[Pycharm won't allow to run a file. Shows run unittest option only.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835466/pycharm-wont-allow-to-run-a-file-shows-run-unittest-option-only)
and tried the suggested solution, but it still showed "Run doctests in 'foo.py'" in context menu.

Comment: What is the content of the file?

Comment: http://www.codeshare.io/tbM8u sorry for the slow reply

Comment: So when you right click inside `if __name__ == '__main__'` block there is no Run script option?

Comment: Well, I tried it and the solution in [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835466/pycharm-wont-allow-to-run-a-file-shows-run-unittest-option-only) works fine.

Answer (score 10):

Just had the same issue. In my case, I had a '>>>' string within the docs of a function:

```
def foo(x):
    """Do foo.
    Example:
    >>>foo(1)
    # Out: 1
    """
    return x
```

I had to comment out `# >>>foo(1)` and delete the run config under Run > Edit Configurations (minus symbol).

Comment: I had exactly this issue, thanks a ton.

Answer (score 4):

I'm having the same **Run 'Doctests in __init__'** issue with PyCharm 2016. I'm not sure if this is due to the same problem other people are having, but this is my fix.

I noticed the file that won't run lives in a resource directory:

[image: click here for image]

Once I opened a new PyCharm project with the script I want to run **not** in a resource directory, PyCharm ran it with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Mine is PyCharm 2023.2 (Community Edition) and if I right click inside the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block there is a Run "filename" option. Outside you can just start the Docstring tests.

Thanks to @Mehraban who mentioned in the comment above.