# Python3 HTMLTestRunner not generating report

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm giving it a try to Selenium+Python and after having researched a little bit about a nice way to generate a report I run into "HTMLTestRunner", the thing is that I've looked for a lot of examples on the internet and they're all the same however when I try to get it to work on my code (pressing play mostly), I can't see the report generated and I'm not getting any error , Can you giving me a hand please? This is the code I'm using:
python36
selenium 3.3.1
pycharm Community Edition 2016.3.2

```
# coding=utf-8
import unittest
import HTMLTestRunner
import os
from test_project.count import Count

# get the directory path to output report file
result_dir = os.getcwd()

class TestCount(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.j =Count(2,3)

    def test_add(self):
        self.add = self.j.add()
        self.assertEqual(self.add,5)

    def tesrDown(self):
        pass
# get all tests from SearchProductTest and HomePageTest class
if __name__ == '__main__':
    suit = unittest.TestSuite()
    suit.addTest(TestCount("test_add"))
    smoke_tests = unittest.TestSuite(suit)
    outfile = open(result_dir + '\SmokeTestReport.html', 'wb')
    runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(stream=outfile,
                                       title='Test Report',
                                       description='Smoke Tests')
    runner.run(smoke_tests)
```

It is work after I remove main part. Anyone can tell me why?

```
# coding=utf-8
import unittest
import HTMLTestRunner
import os
from test_project.count import Count

# get the directory path to output report file
result_dir = os.getcwd()

class TestCount(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.j =Count(2,3)

    def test_add(self):
        self.add = self.j.add()
        self.assertEqual(self.add,5)

    def tesrDown(self):
        pass

suit = unittest.TestSuite()
suit.addTest(TestCount("test_add"))


smoke_tests = unittest.TestSuite(suit)


outfile = open(result_dir + '\SmokeTestReport.html', 'wb')

# configure HTMLTestRunner options
runner = HTMLTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(stream=outfile,
                                       title='Test Report',
                                       description='Smoke Tests')

# run the suite using HTMLTestRunner
runner.run(smoke_tests)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't run Unittest in your program. It will not execute main part.
Just edit configuration to run your script.

like this:
From the Run menu > Run > edit configuration > select/add ScriptName.py above Python instead of Unittests in ScriptName.py

reference:
[pycharm-wont-allow-to-run-a-file-shows-run-unittest-option-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20835466/pycharm-wont-allow-to-run-a-file-shows-run-unittest-option-only/50403172)