# How create a report with htmltestrunner?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

My class:

```py
import unittest,pytest, HtmlTestRunner


class groupTests(unittest.TestCase,Browser):

    def setUp(self):
    code
    def tearDown(self):
    code
    def test_first(self):
        code test

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output='./report'))
```

Python 3.6.7

does not receive the report file. maybe I'm doing something wrong. how to improve my code? Maybe I can't use last if structure ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just try to edit configuration of IDE to execute your script.

In PyCharm:

From the Run menu > Run > edit configuration >

**select/add ScriptName.py above Python** instead of Unittests in ScriptName.py

[image]

Reference: [Python3 HTMLTestRunner not generating report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42945583/python3-htmltestrunner-not-generating-report/)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer, but 
continue the same problem , how I can change this? Maybe other plugin?